# Samba AD replication issues - NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Tags: samba, samba4

We are having issues with our Samba AD servers running on CentOS 6.5 OS.
Our samba4 AD setup was working fine for years. It's a master replica setup, hosting AD and DNS records. We noticed our client servers failing to communicate with the ad server and checking the logs, we noticed below errors. I don't know much about samba, so if you need any specific informations please ask .

```
samba[16271]:   Failed to bind to uuid e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2 for e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2@ncacn_ip_tcp:
705f4d78-4075-40db-b330-b5e40963cc8f
._msdcs.xxxxxx[1024,seal,krb5] NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

Replica is broken as well:

```
/usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool drs showrepl
Last attempt @ Thu Oct  6 09:09:14 2022 EDT failed, result 31 (WERR_GENERAL_FAILURE)
                151686 consecutive failure(s).
                Last success @ NTTIME(0)
```

How can we fix this? Please help.

Update 1:
Further, I tried to run samba_dnsupdate --verbose --all-names
It failed with:

```
RuntimeError: kinit for XXXX  failed (Preauthentication failed)
```

Update 2:
Samba Version 4.1.12.
samba_dnsupdate was run as root.
System time is in sync with NTP and is correct.

Comment: @roaima OS is CentOS 6.5, Samba 4. Yes it was working for years fine.

Comment: Ok. So our samba4 AD setup was working fine for years. Its a master replica setup, hosting AD and DNS records. We noticed our client servers failing to communicate with ad server and checking the logs, we noticed above issues.
I dont know much about samba, so if you need any specific informations please ask, I am happy to provide.

Comment: @roaima, done 
Please let me know what you think about this issue.

Comment: "_Our samba4 AD setup was working fine for years_" - what changed?

Comment: @roima, I dont think any changes happened to break it

Comment: Check the basics - can the server resolve its own hostname? Also in the fully-qualified form? In other words, try `getent hosts $(hostname -s)` and `getent hosts $(hostname -f)`. Both should return an IP address that points back to the host itself.

Comment: Thanks @telcoM. I can confirm hostnames are resolving back to the right hosts.

Comment: Further, I tried to run samba_dnsupdate --verbose --all-names
It failed with:
RuntimeError: kinit for XXXX  failed (Preauthentication failed)

Comment: Have you run through the basic [Samba Troubleshooting](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_Troubleshooting) steps on the wiki? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/719929/edit) to include your discoveries and feedback.